# Recursive CAML query

Tags: caml, query

I would like to search items between two dates in a DocumentLibrary. The query find the files at root just right.
However the query doesn't seem to be considering files in folders.

Here is my attempt :

```
var listToQuery = web.Lists["Pages"]; 
var formatedStartDate = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate));
var formatedEndDate   = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate));

 var query = new SPQuery
            {
                Query =
                    @"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedStartDate +
                    "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedEndDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>",
                ViewAttributes = "scope=\"RecursiveAll\"",
                Folder = listToQuery.RootFolder
            };

   var result = listToQuery.GetItems(query).Count;
```

Am I missing something ? Why does the "RecursiveAll" doesn't seem to do anything ?

Comment: try    scope=\"Recursive\""

Comment: remove the `Folder = listToQuery.RootFolder` line and try

Comment: Same (wrong) result with Recursive instead of recursiveall and without specifying the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the folder attribute, thats why its not querying all folders. 
Try it as below:

```
var listToQuery = web.Lists["Pages"]; 
var formatedStartDate = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate));
var formatedEndDate   = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate));

 var query = new SPQuery
            {
                Query =
                    @"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedStartDate +
                    "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                    formatedEndDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>",
                ViewAttributes = "scope=\"RecursiveAll\""                
            };

   var result = listToQuery.GetItems(query).Count;
```

Or a simpler one:

```
var listToQuery = web.Lists["Pages"]; 
var formatedStartDate = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate));
var formatedEndDate   = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate));


SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = 
      @"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                formatedStartDate +
                "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='SAG_PublicationDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                formatedEndDate + 
                "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";

var result = listToQuery.GetItems(query).Count;
```

Comment: I got the same result without specifying the folder.  I tried GetItems().Count to check if i could find all files, and it worked. So basically recursion happens, and i suppose for some reason the files in the folders are rejected in the test but not the files at root, i don't know why yet

Comment: Tried an empty query, recursion happened. I suppose the problem is in the query, maybe because folders don't have a publication date ?

Comment: It was working, it was the test that was faulty.